# Cannot Sign-in to Wordpress Admin Panel

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

Problem

I cannot access the admin panel for my wordpress website. I use the same login I have been using for months and all that happens is the site refreshes with no error code to speak of.

Envoirnment:

- Wordpress 5
- AWS Lightsail micro instance running Bitnami's Wordpress configs

Troubleshooting steps I have tried (none of which has worked):

1. Disabling all the plugins (This used to work 100% of the time with this issue but isn't now)
2. Disabling all the themes
3. Replacing the the wp-login file with a fresh one
4. Deleting the .htaccess file
5. Restarting the lightsail instance via the command line and the lightsail console
6. Clearing my cache/cookies
7. Create a new instance using a snapshot
8. Creating a new user via phpMyAdmin and attempting to login (I would get a message saying I entered the wrong password)

Is there another troubleshooting step I can take? If I cannot access the admin panel is there a way I can copy the content of the site to a new server and start fresh there?

Comment: Have you tried checking the developer console to see what causes the refresh? You might also encounter some error messages there.

Comment: If you're referring to the browser console, I have looked and found no errors there either.

Comment: I faced the same problem and I tried many things to solve the problem but I couldn't find the solution. Finally I tried logging in using a different browser and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You can take a look at the list of users in the database to see if your user there.

```
mysql -u root -p bitnami_wordpress -e "SELECT * FROM wp_users;"
```

You can update the user's password by running this command

```
mysql -u root -p bitnami_wordpress -e "UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass=MD5('NEW_PASSWORD_HERE') WHERE ID='ADMIN-ID';"
```

> Please substitute NEW_PASSWORD_HERE with the password you want to use.

You can learn more about this here

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/reset-wp-admin-password/

Comment: Although I'm only able to use the new user I created in step 8 from my troubleshooting. I followed this step with the original and it isn't working. 

Is there a chance the user was corrupted?

Comment: I don't know if the process you followed to create a new user in the application using phpMyAdmin is the correct one or not. You should check the WordPress' documentation and its forums to know if you did it correctly. I understand you missed steps or configured the password erroneously and that's why you are getting that error message when trying to use the user.